# How to fix CondaOSError: OS error: failed to link?

Tags: python, anaconda

Something got broken in my anaconda installation, and when I try to update packages, or install certain packages in the root environment, I get:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ...
    qt:              4.8.7-4    
    ...

Linking packages ...


CondaOSError: OS error: failed to link (src=u'/Users/usernmae/anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.7-4/mkspecs/default', dst='/Users/username/anaconda/mkspecs/default', type=3, error=OSError(17, 'File exists'))
```

I have conda version 4.2.11, which I thin is the latest.

qt is a dependency for many packages, and is important.  Is there a way to fix this without a complete reinstallation of anaconda?

---

[There is a GitHub issue which appears related](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3494#issuecomment-260947604), with lots of people complaining, but no clear solution.

Comment: anyone have any luck with this yet? I'm stuck.